# Regex to replace spaces in file link

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-extensions

I'm processing some text using C# and I need a regex to replace the spaces in a file link with `%20`. So given this text:

```
/*
**  2 > 1
**  1 < 2 
**  <file:\\\server\dir one\dirtwo\file name.txt>
**  <just because>
**  1 < 2
**  2 > 1
**  <file:\\\server\dir one\dirtwo\file name.txt>
**  2 > 1
*/
```

The result would be:

```
/*
**  2 > 1
**  1 < 2 
**  <file:\\\server\dir%20one\dirtwo\file%20name.txt>
**  <just because>
**  1 < 2
**  2 > 1
**  <file:\\\server\dir%20one\dirtwo\file%20name.txt>
**  2 > 1
*/
```

So far I've come up with this pattern `\x20(?=(?:(?!<file:).)*>)` but it matches some of the spaces that are outside of the file link.

Ideally I'd like to do this just using regex. The text I'm modifying is the current document open in Visual Studio (I've created a VS extension). For some other text changes I'm using the `ReplacePattern` method in `EnvDTE.TextDocument`. I don't have much experience writing extensions so this seemed a lot simpler than anything else I could come up with (I did look at using edit points).

### Solution

There seems to be an issue with using lookbehind or lookahead in a regex using the TextDocument.ReplacePattern method which causes an exception to be raised. Using the same expression in Regex.Replace works as expected. If it wasn't for this issue then the solution(s) provided by Wiktor Stribiżew would be perfect.

To keep things simple I've implemented the following which does the job:

```
bool patternReplaced;
do
{
   patternReplaced = activeDoc.ReplacePattern(@"(<file:\\{3}.*)\s(\S+>)", @"$1%20$2", (int)vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression);
} while (patternReplaced);
```

Comment: can't you do simple `if-else` check and replace?

Comment: Just be very careful with the adjoining patterns that can match one another. I'd suggest `@"(<file:\\{3}[^<>]*)\s([^\s<>]+>)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Regex.Replace` to match the `<file:...>` substrings and replace the spaces using the match evaluator:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"<file:\\{3}[^>]+>", m => m.Value.Replace(" ", "%20"));
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ZD1jzD)

Note that in case there are more than just spaces to escape, you can consider using `Uri.EscapeUriString(m.Value)` (with another regex, like `@"(?<=<file:\\{3}[^<>]*)[^<>\\]+"`).

Another solution using infinite width lookbehind:

```
@"(?<=<file:\\{3}[^<>]*)\s"
```

and replace with `%20`.

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%3Cfile%3A%5C%5C%7B3%7D%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D*)%5Cs&i=%2F*%0D%0A**%20%202%20%3E%201%0D%0A**%20%201%20%3C%202%20%0D%0A**%20%20%3Cfile%3A%5C%5C%5Cserver%5Cdir%20one%5Cdirtwo%5Cfile%20name.txt%3E%0D%0A**%20%20%3Cjust%20because%3E%0D%0A**%20%201%20%3C%202%0D%0A**%20%202%20%3E%201%0D%0A**%20%20%3Cfile%3A%5C%5C%5Cserver%5Cdir%20one%5Cdirtwo%5Cfile%20name.txt%3E%0D%0A**%20%202%20%3E%201%0D%0A*%2F&r=%2520)

Comment: This is a really nice solution, but ideally I'd like to do it with a single regex operation if possible. I've added some more detail to the question to explain my reasoning. I'm open to any ideas though.

Comment: I added another solution. Note that lookbehinds like this are costly in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. The performance isn't a problem for me, but it turns out that there's a bug in `TextDocument.ReplacePattern` that causes it to throw an exception when you use a lookbehind. Do you have any suggestions for how to do it without a lookbehind?

Comment: Is there a flag for specifying a regex? Like `vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression`? `.ReplacePattern(@"(?<=<file:\\{3}[^<>]*)\s", "%20", vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression)` or `.ReplacePattern(@"(?<=<file:\\{3}[^<>]*)\s", "%20", (int)vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression)`

Comment: Yup, the second option in your comment is exactly what I'm using, but I get a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` with the message `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A00B9`. I reduced it down to `.ReplacePattern("(?<=f)", "X", (int)vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression)` and I still get the exception. Other patterns that I'm using that don't have lookbehind work as expected though.

Comment: Looks like there's the same problem with lookahead! I've updated the question with the solution that I'm using, but thanks for your help. If not for the issues with `ReplacePattern` then your answer is spot on. I'll accept it as I think the regex you came up with does answer the question.